# How to find how many times the first letter is repeated in a string using Python?

Tags: python

This apparently simple question is bugging my head for a while, thought somebody might be of help.

I have a simple string

```
s = 'AAABCAA'
```

How to find the number of repetitions of first letter 'A'?
Answer should be 3.

I have tried:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(s)
```

But, this gives 'A' = 5, instead of 3.

Comment: looks like a job for regex

Comment: You can't do it with Counter.

Comment: Chip in guys, time to make some difference!

Comment: Why should the answer be 3? there are 5 'A's overall in the list. Mind clarifying?

Comment: @LeKhan9 I only want first repetitions, if there is anything after A, neglect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `groupby()` to find all letter groups and then you can use `next()` to get the first group from the iterator:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'AAABCAA'

sum(1 for _ in next(groupby(s))[1])
# 3
```

Alternatively you can use the function `takewhile()`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x == s[0], s))
# 3
```

And finally you can use regex:

```
import re

len(re.search(r'^(\w)\1+', s, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(0))
# 3
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a for loop with a break statement.

```
s = 'AAABCAA'
counter=0
firstletter=s[0]
for each in s:
    if each==firstletter:
        counter+=1
    else:
        break
print(counter)
```

This just returns `3`.

Alternatively, you could return index of the first element of the string which is not the same as the first character of your string:

```
import numpy as np
s = 'AAABCAA'
firstletter=s[0]
checklist=[(each==firstletter)*1 for each in s]
print(np.where(np.asarray(checklist)==0)[0][0])
```

In this case, with list comprehension (`[(each==firstletter)*1 for each in s]`) we produce a list:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

The value is `1` wherever the character in that spot is identical to the first character of the string.
Then `np.where(np.asarray(checklist)==0)[0][0]` gives you the index of the first `0` (ie the first character not identical to starting character) of this newly created list.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short solution that uses list comp. Of course, readability won't be the goal here :)

```
repetitions = lambda str, letter: [i + 1 for i, num in enumerate(str) if num == letter][-1]
```

Examples:

```
str = 'BBBBC'
letter = 'B'

repetitions(str, letter) # 4

str = 'AABC'
letter = 'A'

repetitions(str, letter) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for patterns in strings in general, use a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).